Mui: Custom TimepickerToolbar showing default time list of items and also the custom design
I am working on customizing the TimePickerToolbar component from MUI (Material-UI). My main objective is to remove extra space from the default time list in the TimePickerToolbar. Additionally, I aim to implement a custom design to better fit my project's requirements.
I have attempted to adjust the spacing and apply custom styles, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired results. Below is the code I have worked with so far:
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                      <TimePicker
                        views={["hours", "minutes"]}
                        viewRenderers={() => <>Hello</>}
                        slots={{
                          toolbar: CustomToolbar,
                        }}
                        ampm={false}
                        placeholder={t("createCalendarEventModal.Start Time")}
                        className={classes.dateTimePicker}
                        onChange={(newTime) => {
                          setFieldValue("startTime", newTime);
                        }}
                        value={values.startTime}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        error={touched.startTime && errors.startTime}
                        helperText={
                          touched.startTime && (errors.startTime || "")
                        }
                        sx={{
                          "& svg": {
                            fill: "#536886",
                          },
                        }}
                        inputFormat="HH:mm"
                        minTime={minStartTime}
                      />
                    </LocalizationProvider>

Custom toolbar component
import {
  PickersToolbar,
  PickersToolbarButton,
  pickersToolbarClasses,
} from "@mui/x-date-pickers/internals";

const CustomToolbar = ({
  date,
  view,
  onViewChange,
  isLandscape,
  toolbarTitle = "Select Time",
}) => {
  const handleHoursClick = () => {
    if (onViewChange) {
      onViewChange("hours");
    }
  };

  const handleMinutesClick = () => {
    if (onViewChange) {
      onViewChange("minutes");
    }
  };

  return (
    <PickersToolbar className="custom-toolbar" isLandscape={isLandscape}>
      {/* <Typography variant="h6">{toolbarTitle}</Typography> */}
      <PickersToolbarButton
        value={date ? date.getHours() : "--"}
        onClick={handleHoursClick}
        selected={view === "hours"}
        typographyClassName={pickersToolbarClasses.text}
      />
      <Typography variant="h4">:</Typography>
      <PickersToolbarButton
        value={date ? date.getMinutes() : "--"}
        onClick={handleMinutesClick}
        selected={view === "minutes"}
        typographyClassName={pickersToolbarClasses.text}
      />
    </PickersToolbar>
  );
};

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly customize the TimePickerToolbar to remove the extra space and apply the custom design.
Thank you in advance for your help!
